# What else can HTML do besides determine page layout?

Tags: html

My friend and I were recently discussing HTML and web layout (he's just getting started with it) and we came upon an issue: is it possible to do anything with HTML besides determine page layout?

For example, addition

```
int x = 5 + 4;
```

is perfectly valid and easy to use in most languages (looking at you, Erlang). However, is it possible to somehow contort `<html>` to allow for similar functionality? In other words, can `<html>` be forced to be a more basic version of a scripting/interpreted language without any external help (javascript, etc.)? Why or why not?

Personally, until this conversation, I had never even considered the idea, but now it's got me intrigued and I need a definite answer. I figured it can't be possible because HTML is like XML, which is for data storage, not data manipulation.

Comment: HTML doesn't define page layout, that's CSS job. HTML defines the page's content and structure, however. Furthermore, HTML is a *markup language* not a *programming language*. That's what JavaScript is for.

Comment: Its not HTML.. its Scripting language which accomplishes this. HTML is just a Markup language. it only play role in displaying the data. any sort of DOM manipulation can only be achieved through programming language as far as I know.

Comment: Some of the new html5 form elements support more advanced functionality than has been traditionally available with html.

Comment: @Dai But is there any way to force it to manipulate data (i.e., multiple two numbers)? I know it isn't necessarily useful, but I'm just throwing it out there. Could it possibly be used to do simple functions even though it's a markup language?

Comment: You and your friend need to get out more. HTML does not get laid. CSS gets laid.

Comment: @EdHeal Haha, thanks <3 I can try that in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML, as its name suggests is a mark-up language for hypertext. In other words, it describes the elements of data that need to go on a web page.

If you need to do any calculations or other processing, you'll first need to decide WHERE you want it to happen. For example, if you want to do calculations on the browser itself, you should look at languages like Javascript or Java. In some cases, software like Flash are also suitable through their scripting commands.

If you want the calculations to take place on a server using the data from the browser, you're looking at a server-side scripting language like PHP, ASP or JSP.

Take for example PHP... It's a powerful language with database capabilities. But you CANNOT expect to create a simple text box for user input using PHP as its role is on the server. So you shouldn't look at it like a restriction of PHP.

Likewise html has a role and that is to present data on the browser. Calculations should be using a scripting language like Javascript and layouts are **best** done using CSS.

Comment: I understand. I was just wondering if there's a way to force html to accomplish something that would be more easily done with JavaScript. (Just as an oddball idea per se)